# ASP.NET MVC Forcing a PDF to download, not show

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, mime-types

In our code we send a PDF to the client:

```
return new FilePathResult(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(result.PathToPdf), MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(result.PathToPdf));
```

Works fine. However, it appears in the browser, we want the PDF to download to the user's download folder, not appear in the browser.

How is that done?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mean you don't want it to appear in browsers download bar or popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line before return:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;");
```